# survey table issue: The survey table function is showing deferent number of observations than the actual number of observations in the data

Tags: r, survey

```
Data <- data.frame(X =c(1,4,6,4,1,7,3,2,2),Y = c(6,5,9,9,43,65,45,67,90),weight=c(0.1,1.2,4,0,0,5,0.65,1,0))  
  
dat_design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = Data, weights = Data$weight)
    

ab=svytable(~X+Y,design=dat_design) %>% as.data.frame
```

Data= 9 observations and 3 variables

dat_deisgn= list of 9

ab the svytable data frame is showing 48 observations and 3 variables

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your *question* is, but, no.

The `svytable` data frame is showing 48 table cells, one for each of the 48=6*8 combinations of values of `X` and `Y` in the table. That's what it's supposed to do.  The third column is the sum of the weights for observations in the cell; you can see that it adds to the same total as your `weights` variable.